# Inno Setup - Disable (comment-out) all instances of key in INI file

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an INI file that looks, let's say, like this:

```
[Section]
Key=Value
```

I need to change it to look something like this

```
[Section]
;Key=Value
```

And vice-versa. Yes, basically I need to disable the key completely. I tried using `StringChange` and `CompareStr`. The problem is, the specific INI I need to edit has several keys with the same name (Yes, I am sure it is an II, it is correct, and it should be that way. The value is different each time), So `CompareStr` isn't of much help in this case. Which function would be more practical in this case?

Comment: Sorry, i was at work. I need to disable them all, actually. But I want to handle them separately, so I can check that all of them are enabled/disabled. What about the vice versa? I need to see if the line is commented out, and uncomment it. Or do I need to create a separate question for that?

Comment: That's what I was trying to use b4 posting the question, But I had to use `CompareStr` to find out if it was disable. As you can see (in my other question), it didn't work. But I'll try your suggestion about trimming soon as I get home.

Comment: "StringChange already does the comparison" - not sure I understand what you mean by this. The file I need to edit actually has three keys with same name (and different values). I need Inno to check if all three are disabled (semicolon present) and return a rue result (only if all three are disabled, if at least one of them isn't disabled it should return false). Now, I've tried using `CompareStr` to see the current "condition" of the key (enabled/disabled). Now I'm back from, and I'll try what you suggested (about trimming). Still I've never heard of `StringChange` doing any sort of comparison

Comment: You keep changing topic. Your previous asked for a way to disable all enabled lines or to enable all disabled lines. That's what `StringChange` can do, with some limitation (your original post was titled *"Edit INI Key Name"*). Now you ask for a function that checks if there are any enabled/disabled keys. So what do you want really?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment-out the first instance of the `Key=`, use the [`Pos` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_pos) to find it and insert the `;` using the [`Insert` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_insert):

```pascal
function DisableTheFirstKey(var INI: string; Key: string): Boolean;
var
  P: Integer;
begin
  P := Pos(Key + '=', INI);
  Result := (P > 0);
  if Result then
    Insert(';', INI, P);
end;
```

---

If you want to comment out all instances of the `Key=`, use the [`StringChangeEx` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchangeex). To skip the already commented-out lines, make sure the `Key=` is preceded by a new line character (LF = `#10`).

```pascal
{ Inserts ; in front of all Key=... lines. }
{ Keeps the already commented lines intact. }
{ Returns true if any replacement was done. }
{ Works for files with Windows-style EOLs only (CRLF) }
function DisableAllKeys(var INI: string; Key: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (StringChangeEx(INI, #10 + Key + '=', #10 + ';' + Key + '=', False) > 0);
end;

{ Removes the ; from all ;Key=... lines. }
{ Keeps the already enabled lines intact. }
{ Returns true if any replacement was done. }
{ Works for files with Windows-style EOLs only (CRLF) }
function EnableAllKeys(var INI: string; Key: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (StringChangeEx(INI, #10 + ';' + Key + '=', #10 + Key + '=', False) > 0);
end;
```

Comment: Adding this to my code results in error "Variable expected" at the first line of my `code` section, which is `var
  AppLoc: String;`

Comment: Either you didn't copy whole my code or there's some conflict with your code. Don't you use symbols `DisableAllKeys` or `EnableAllKeys` in your code already? It's just not possible for us to find out what's wrong with so little information.

Comment: I got the script working, using `StringChange`. Not sure where to post it, though. Should I just edit the question?

Comment: Why do you want to post it? Do you mean you've used a different solution than the one I've proposed? In that case, post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using this (not without Martin's help, that is):

```
function DisabeMovies: Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: String;
begin
if Standalone then
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc(''))
else
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc('')) + '\FrankenStein\';
  LoadStringFromFile(AppLoc + 'Base.ini', A);
  U := A;
        StringChange(U, 'Key=Value1', ';Key=Value1');
        StringChange(U, 'Key=Value2', ';Key=Value2');
        StringChange(U, 'Key=Value3', ';Key=Value3');
  A := U;
        SaveStringToFile(AppLoc + 'Base', A, False);
End;

function EnableMovies: Boolean;
var
  A: AnsiString;
  U: String;
begin
if Standalone then
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc(''))
else
  AppLoc := RemoveQuotes(CurrentAppLoc('')) + '\FrankenStein\';
  LoadStringFromFile(AppLoc + 'Base.ini', A);
  U := A;
        StringChange(U, ';Key=Value1', 'Key=Value1');
        StringChange(U, ';Key=Value2', 'Key=Value2');
        StringChange(U, ';Key=Value3', 'Key=Value3');
  A := U;
        SaveStringToFile(AppLoc + 'Base.ini', A, False);
End;
```

The only problem is that `Disable Movies` does not result in, e.g. `;Key=Value1`, but it's `;;;Key=Value1` for whatever reason, but it still works.

Thanks a lot to Martin for so much patience. There have been a few miscommunication issues, mainly because, though I know what want, I don't know how to "form" the correct question.